# Turning public items into private items - Java, IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I just wonder if there is a way to make public items (fields, methods) private with a simple button or something

```
public Group wQ;
public Group wA1;
public Group wA2;
public Group wA3;
public Group wG1;
public Group wG2;
public Group wG3;
public Group wS1;
public Group wS2;
public Group wB1;
public Group wB2;
```

For example make all these fields private in one step, without replacing public with private. I use IntelliJ IDEA btw.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to extend the cursor downwards, enabling you to type on multiple lines at once. Try dragging middle click down (possibly it). An alternative is find/replace, of course.

Comment: Yeah I used the find/replace method but it seems so inefficient

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called **Encapsulate fields**.

1. **Right-click** inside of the class you want to edit
2. Select **Refactor**.
3. Select **Encapsulate Fields...**
   [image: screenshot]
4. Check the checkboxes next to all public fields
   [image: GIF]
5. You may then configure to provide both set/get access via accessors or just get access with the checkboxes below.
6. Select **Refactor**.

Note that this method generates getters (and, if you choose so, setters too) for all fields you select. If you don't want these getters, you can choose one of the other options or simply delete the generated getters. It seems like there is no way to opt out of creating getters.

---

Alternatively, you can use **multi-line selections**.

1. Set your cursor at the end of the first `public` keyword.
2. Hold down your **middle mouse button**.
3. Drag the mouse down to the end of the `public` block.
4. Edit the lines simultaneously by using backspace/typing the new `private` keyword.
   [image: GIF]

---

As a third method, you may use **Find and replace**. It has some nifty options which give you great control over what you are doing.

1. Select the menu **Edit**.
2. Select **Find**.
3. Select **Replace**.

   [image: screenshot]
4. Select the text block with the `public` fields.
5. Select **Regex**, **Match Case** and **In Selection**.
6. In the upper field, enter `^(\s*)public(.*)$`.
7. In the lower field, enter `$1private$2`.
8. All replacements will now be highlighted. Review them whether they are correct. You can step through them with the blue arrows next to the upper text box.

   [image: GIF]
9. Select **Replace all**.

Comment: Very nice post, you could give some more credibility and put a reference on THE [refactoring reference from martin fowler](http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) which coined the term and made them become popular in nowadays IDEs which are just automated implementations of his proposed catalog of the most common refactorings.

Comment: There are still too many people out there not knowing of automated refactorings, go out and preach the message ;)

Comment: Very nice post, really appreciate all the animations you made. Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's a video on the above: https://youtu.be/g5jBP-vrX0E

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@RAnders00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36102806/441662), there's another way that lets IntelliJ do it automatically without generating setters/getters whilst also checking if you would break code:

> Rightclick on the class or package → Analyze → Run Inspection by Name → [Declaration access can be weaker](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/12/intellij-idea-16-eap-144-2608-is-out/)

IntelliJ will search your class for members that can have a reduced visiblity based on usage. After scanning you can have it updated automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I would use CTRL+R to find&replace "public" by "private".

Comment: The problem with this approach is you might end up making some public methods private.